# Cannot login after Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 upgrade

Tags: login, 17.04

I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 16.10 server to Ubuntu 17.04 server without trouble. When the system was done and rebooted, I noticed that I couldn't login via SSH. This is the error I'm getting when trying to SSH into the server

```
Connection reset by 192.168.1.100 port 22
```

I hooked up a monitor to the machine and noticed no errors. However, when trying to log in directly on the machine itself it does not prompt me for a password and goes back to the blank screen with the username prompt. It's almost as if the upgrade removed my user.

I've not found any related issues on the internet and I'm a bit worried now as I cannot access the system in any way. I've tried rebooting multiple times. The system itself however seems to be running fine, I can access it's web server etc.

Comment: And suddenly right after I posted this and rebooted once more it prompted me for a password and I could log in again. What caused this? I'm using ZFS file system, but not for the root of the OS, I did see some errors and it was something to do with the disk/partition the OS is installed on. I'll have to investigate this further.